# Is there any way to create an annotated tag from GitHub?

Tags: github

It appears that when a release is created on GitHub it is a light weight tag. Is there any way to create a release in GitHub that is an annotated tag? To clarify, I'm asking if there is a way to do this from the GitHub UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, github's UI does not support annotated tags (yet), but there is a feature request out for this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/752#issuecomment-226418384

Note the workaround in the response from the github employee:

> As a workaround you can create annotated signed tags via the command and push it up to the repository.
>   When creating a release you should then be able to choose this tag from the list.

For now we're stuck creating an annotated tag with the `git tag -a` option.